# Is turning off a power strip adequate?

Tags: electrical

When using power strips, is it OK leave all the electronics, such as TV etc. plugged in and just turn the power off when leaving on vacation?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's fine. If yearning for extra certainty or lightning resistance, unplug the strip (leaving everything plugged into it.)

Comment: Exactly this. Turning off is adequate, but the strip, and everything plugged in is still vulnerable to lightning and other high voltage surges.

Comment: I have replaced (nearly) all my boring strips with surge suppressor strips, but nothing suppresses surges quite like being disconnected from the powerline. The SS does help when things are actually in use, though.

Comment: Note: Whole house surge protectors are meant to take the brunt of a surge, leaving the individual strips to take whatever remains.  Turning off the strip offers more protection than leaving it on, and less protection than unplugging it.